# Remove spaces between delimiter

Tags: powershell

I have many Data Text file which need to fix the spacing issue, 
for example:

```
Name    |   First Name   |  Second Name  |Last Name
```

The Expected Output should be as below:

```
Name|First Name|Second Name|Last Name   (This is I want to achieve)
```

When I use below script its gives its gives me output removing spaces between the sentence as well so can not use, any idea to fix this script:

```
Get-Content File.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' ' } > trimfile.txt
```

Output:

```
Name|FirstName|SecondName|LastName   (Wrong)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using a positiv lookahead and lookbehind to avoid replacing the spaces inside your string:

```
Get-Content File.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(?<=\|)\s+|\s+(?=\|)' } > trimfile.txt
```

Comment: Can not user your code as it is giving me the same result as below
Output:

Name|FirstName|SecondName|LastName   (Wrong)
Removes all the spaces, including single space between string

Comment: When i use your suggested code as below
Get-Content File.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\s+|' } > trimfile.txt
| is my delimiter in file, I get below result
Name|    First Name|    Second Name|Last Name, 
so its removed the blank before the | but not after the |

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer - please give it a shot

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, ITS WORKING NOW

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider to accept the answer.